# Unit Tests in the Eliom Framework

Tags: unit-testing, ocaml, js-of-ocaml, ocsigen

I am building a new project using Eliom and having trouble setting up a compilation process for unit tests using OUnit.

I have two files:

```
 Js_Client_Code.eliom - contains all of the client side code
 Project.eliom - contains all of the server side code (including opening Js_Client_Code.eliom)
```

I have set up the files in this way so that I can run unit tests on Js_Client_Code.eliom without using `ocsigenserver`.

This is my current makefile for the tests:

```
 test: prep unit_tests     

 prep:
     eliomc -infer Js_Client_Code.eliom
     js_of_eliom -linkall -a Js_Client_Code.eliom -o file_a.cma
     eliomc -a -linkall Js_Client_Code.eliom -o file_b.cma

 # Code is here to move the cma files back to the parent directory, since they are written to _client/ and _server/ by default

 unit_tests:
     ocamlfind ocamlc -thread -syntax camlp4o -package ounit,js_of_ocaml.syntax \
     -linkpkg -g -o UnitTests file_a.cma file_b.cma unit_tests.ml
```

Running `make test` in the shell produces

```
 File "unit_tests.ml", line 1:
 Error: Error while linking file_a.cma(Js_Client_Code):
 Reference to undefined global `Eliom_client'
```

Am I misunderstanding the Eliom/Js_of_ocaml compilation process, or just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking the eliom libraries at all, so of course it's missing all the external modules.

Honestly, I don't think you'll manage to unit test modules that depends on eliom that way. It would probably be easier to unit test the non-eliom part indivdually, and do end-to-end browser-based tests (there are lot's of framework for that).

If you really want to try, there are explanations on eliom (or ocsigenserver)'s manual to link statically.